# 'You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>' debugging react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and am having a hard time debugging it.

I have the below code: App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as BooksAPI from './data/BooksAPI';
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

const BookSearch = observer(class BookSearch extends Component{

    state = observable({
        query: '',
        books: []
    })

  searchBooks = (query) =>{
    this.setState({ query: query.trim() });
    BooksAPI.search(query, 20).then((books) =>{
      this.setState({ books: books });
    })
  }

    render(){

        const { query } = this.state;
        const bookSearch =  this.state.books.map((book) => 
                <li key={book.id}>
                    <div className="book">
                        <div className="book-top">
                            <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${ book.imageLinks.thumbnail })` }}></div>
                            <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                                <select onChange={(event) => this.props.bookChange(book, event.target.value)}>
                                    <option>Move to...</option>
                                    <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
                                    <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
                                    <option value="read">Read</option>
                                    <option value="none">None</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="book-title">{ book.title }</div>
                        <div className="book-authors">{ book.authors.map((author) => 
                            <span key={ author + book.title } >{ author }</span>
                        )}</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            ) ;

        return(
            
            <div className="App">   
            <div className="search-books">
                <div className="search-books-bar">
                    <Link className="close-search" to='/'>Close</Link>
                    <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">

                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Search by title or author"     
                            onChange={ this.searchBooks}
                        />  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="search-books-results">
                    <div className="bookshelf">
                <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{ this.state.query }</h2>
                <div className="bookshelf-books">
                    <ol className="books-grid">
                        { bookSearch }
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            </div>
        )
    }
})

export default BookSearch
```

And index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

It continues to trip on `ReactDom.render(..` - being new to react, this concept is confusing to me. The only real error or output is the following: `'You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>'`

I can't figure out how to console log in react, so am a bit confused on how to remedy this issue.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how `console.log` would help here (and you use it the same way in React as you do any other JS). The error message seems quite clear.

Comment: You are correct, I am not worthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation you need to wrap your whole `App` with the `Router` component, so `Link can have access to it.

https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

So basically:

Before the `<div className="App">`   wrap this with

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

...


return (
  <Router>
    .. your stuff
  <Router/>
)
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for taking a look! Still grasping the react concepts